# 22.04 load-from-cold using much less space than 20.04 to 22.04 upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, storage, cleanup

I need to determine which approach is going to result in a smaller final disk size, so I tested two scenarios...

- Install `20.04 server` and immediately upgrade to `22.04` -- **this used 5.5 GB**, even after autoclean, autoremove, etc
- Install `22.04 server` (both minimal and standard) -- **this used around 4.2 GB** and 'minimal' was even less

My question is...  why the large gap between the two approaches?  I might expect a minor difference of 50-100MB, but certainly not 1.3GB.

Is there anything I can do to trim the extra fat from the `do-release-upgrade` route?

**Edit**: Seems the upgraded disk has `/snap` at almost 1GB (compared to almost 0GB), a `/usr` folder 300MB larger and `/var` folder about 450MB larger. Getting rid of snaps is obviously part of the solution, but why the `/usr` and `/var` differences?

Comment: For /var, system logs can take up a lot of space, my /var/log folder on a recent install of 22.04 is over 4GB, so I don't find it surprising that 450 MB worth of logs are generated during the upgrade. It'd be interesting to see if there is a difference in the long term, when the log folders have filled up. I'm not sure about /usr but maybe some application files weren't removed after apt uninstalled them?